# Deploy de uma API SpringBoot (JAR) em um Host HTTPS

Tags: deploy

Estou tendo um problema ao realizar deploy de um JAR em um servidor VPS (Hostgator). O deploy do front (angular) foi bem sucedido. No entanto, construí uma  API para teste (HelloWorld). No application.properties coloquei as seguintes configurações:

server.port=9443
server.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=*****

Gerei o jar com mvn clean install e criei uma pasta em /home/usuario/ea-tomcat85/webapps/api e coloquei o jar nessa pasta. Executei o comando : java  -Dspring.profiles.active=prod  -jar *.jar

**A aplicação inicia na porta 9443:**

[image: Api iniciada]

Até este, tudo certo, porém, ao executar um teste com o comando 'curl' com a opção -v (https://meusite.com.br:9443/teste), **uma mensagem no console informa que o certificado é invalido:**

[image: Erro certificado inválido]

Se eu coloco a opção -k, funciona, porém, no modo 'inseguro'.

O meu servidor é um VPS que já está habilitado o https com certificado.

Perguntas:
1) Sendo o meu host https, preciso configurar o 'properties' habilitando o https?
2) Se sim, quais os passos  para fazer o deploy de um Jar em um host https?
3) Preciso configurar um **self sign** mesmo meu domínio já possuindo um certificado válido?

Desde já , agradeço a ajuda.